# How can I get a relation between flux and charge from memristor schematic?

Tags: voltage, current, amplifier, resistors, ground

I am simulating the schematic of the memristor and getting a response between current and voltage. From this, how can I get a relation between flux and charge? I also did not get the current and voltage probe from the library of LTSPICE, how can I find it?

[image]

Comment: SPICE doesn't have voltage and current probes as circuit elements. You measure voltage and current (and other quantities) by using the relevant expressions in the graph panel.

Comment: then how to integrate this i mean how i get flux and charge relationship i spice